# Question about updating state and hooks (possibly typescript related)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

another question here. I did figure out a solution that works but I was curious on getting some other ideas that might be better. Basically what I am trying to do is enter some colors into an input and add to an array of objects. There's also validation tied to it to prevent unique colors or color names.

Here's my working solution:

```
UseState hooks:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState("teal");
const [colors, setColors] = useState([{ color: "", name: "" }]);
const [newName, setNewName] = useState("");


useEffect hook for the validation:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

useEffect(() => {
        ValidatorForm.addValidationRule("isColorNameUnique", value => {
            return colors.every(({ name }: any) => {
                console.log(name);
                return name.toLowerCase() !== value.toLowerCase();
            });
        });

        ValidatorForm.addValidationRule("isColorUnique", value => {
            return colors.every(({ color }: any) => color !== currentColor);
        });
    });


function that gets called when submitted:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const addNewColor = () => {
        const newColor = {
            color: currentColor,
            name: newName
        };

        if (
            Object.keys(colors[0].color).length === 0 &&
            Object.keys(colors[0].name).length === 0
        ) {
            setColors([newColor]);
        } else {
            setColors([...colors, newColor]);
        }

        setNewName("");
    };
```

So if I had

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState([{}]);

const addNewColor = () => {
        const newColor = {
            color: currentColor,
            name: newName
        };

        setColors([...colors, newColor]);

        setNewName("");
    };
```

the validation logic gives errors about "can't read property name of undefined" which makes sense. I tried adding logic to the validation itself to prevent this which works for getting rid of that error but it's still adding an empty object as first index in the array.

This way also works

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState([{color: "", name: ""]);

const addNewColor = () => {
        const newColor = {
            color: currentColor,
            name: newName
        };

        setColors([...colors, newColor]);

        setNewName("");
    };
```

but then it defaults to first index being empty object like 
{color: "", name: ""} and it never gets replaced.

If I do

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState([]);

const addNewColor = () => {
        const newColor = {
            color: currentColor,
            name: newName
        };

        setColors([...colors, newColor]);

        setNewName("");
    };
```

I get this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iXeZ.png

Is there another way to get this to work with passing the validation and not having empty object in the state that's useless.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

since you're using typescript, why not introduce interface for the color

```
interface IColor {
  color: string,
  name: string,
}
```

and initialise your state hooks by doing:

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState<IColor[]>([]);
```

then, pushing colors to the array would be like:

```
const newColor: IColor = {
  color: currentColor,
  name: newName
};

setColors([...colors, newColor]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to check on this. I will try to asap, thanks!